# How can I roll-over in java?

Tags: java

I am coding for `public void addMinutes` right now.

An input like `1570minutes` means "2 hours 10 minutes", and `65minutes` is "1 hour 5 minutes", I have to increase it by 1 hour for every 60 minutes.

```
public class AlarmClockController {

    public AlarmClockController() {
    }
    public void addHours(int hours) {
        if (hours < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < hours; i++) {
            this.theClock.incrementHour();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void addMinutes(int minutes) {
        if (minutes < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < minutes; i++) {
            if (minutes < 60) {
                this.theClock.incrementMinutes();
            }
            else { 

            }
        }
        
    public AlarmClock getTheClock() {
        return this.theClock;
    }
    
}

public class AlarmClock {

    private int hour;
    private int minutes;
    

    public AlarmClock() {
        this.hour = 0;
        this.minutes = 0;
    }
    
    AND getSeconds()==0

    public AlarmClock(int hour, int minutes) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour should be between 0 and 23");
        }
        
        if (minutes < 0 || minutes > 59) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("minutes shoulbe be between 0 and 59");
        }
        
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return this.hour;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return this.minutes;
    }
    
    public void incrementHour() {
        this.hour = (this.hour + 1) % 24;
    }

    public void incrementMinutes() {
        this.minutes = (this.minutes + 1) % 60;
    }
}
```

This is for testing:

```
public class TestAddMinutes {

    @Test
    public void testShouldNotAllowMinutesLessThanZero() {
        // Arrange: create a controller
        AlarmClockController controller = new AlarmClockController();
        
        // Act & Assert: call addMinutes with a negative value
        // and assert it throws an exception
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            controller.addMinutes(-1);
        });
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testShouldAddZeroMinutes() {
        // Arrange: create a controller
        AlarmClockController controller = new AlarmClockController();
        
        // Act: call the method with an appropriate parameter
        controller.addMinutes(0);
        
        // Assert: that the clock has the expected number of minutes
        AlarmClock clock = controller.getTheClock();
        assertEquals(0, clock.getHour());
        assertEquals(0, clock.getMinutes());
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldAddOneMinute() {
        // Arrange: create a controller
        AlarmClockController controller = new AlarmClockController();
        
        // Act: call the method with an appropriate parameter
        controller.addMinutes(1);
        
        // Assert: that the clock has the expected number of minutes
        AlarmClock clock = controller.getTheClock();
        assertEquals(0, clock.getHour());
        assertEquals(1, clock.getMinutes());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testShouldAddSeveralMinutes() {
        // Arrange: create a controller
        AlarmClockController controller = new AlarmClockController();
        
        // Act: call the method with an appropriate parameter
        controller.addMinutes(10);
        
        // Assert: that the clock has the expected number of minutes
        AlarmClock clock = controller.getTheClock();
        assertEquals(0, clock.getHour());
        assertEquals(10, clock.getMinutes());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testShouldAddSeveralMinutesWithMinutesRollover() {
        // Arrange: create a controller
        AlarmClockController controller = new AlarmClockController();
        
        // Act: call the method with an appropriate parameter
        controller.addMinutes(65);
        
        // Assert: that the clock has the expected number of minutes
        AlarmClock clock = controller.getTheClock();
        assertEquals(1, clock.getHour());
        assertEquals(5, clock.getMinutes());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testShouldAddSeveralMinutesWithHoursRollover() {
        // Arrange: create a controller
        AlarmClockController controller = new 
        AlarmClockController();
        
        // Act: call the method with an appropriate parameter
        controller.addMinutes(26*60 + 10);
        
        // Assert: that the clock has the expected number of minutes
        AlarmClock clock = controller.getTheClock();
        assertEquals(2, clock.getHour());
        assertEquals(10, clock.getMinutes());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with the issue you are facing with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside `addMinutes` should be:

```java
if (minutes < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
int hours = minutes/60;
for(int i = 0; i<hours; i++) {
    this.theClock.incrementHour();
}
minutes %= 60; // remaining minutes
for(int i = 0; i < minutes; i++) {
   this.theClock.incrementMinutes();
}
```

Also, I would recommend not to increment the hours and minutes one by one.
Replace the increment methods using the below template:

```java
public void incrementHours(int value) {
    this.hour = (this.hour + value) % 24; 
}
```